# Probability and binomials choosing phones

Tags: probability, statistics

So assume we have 100 phones of some sort and that we choose 15 of them. We know that on average 6 of them are faulty and 94 are fine. What is the probability of us choosing 15 phones from the 100 so that non of them is faulty?

I tried writing the binomial function as:
$$ \frac{{{94}\choose{15}}{{6}\choose{0}}}{{{100}\choose{15}}} $$

But this is approximately =0.3 but I expect an answer of 0.77. What should I be doing to make it right?

Comment: You have used the hypergeometric distribution, not the binomial distribution.

Comment: @callculus42, sorry I dont understand how I should change the answer

Comment: The difference is whether we have a factory that produces tens of thousands of phones (*some amount sufficiently greater than our sample size*) that we randomly sampled from and so we might have potentially had more than six or less than six faulty phones in which case the binomial distribution is more appropriate... or if we have a factory that produced *exactly* $100$ phones and we know that *exactly* six are faulty in which case the hypergeometric distribution is more appropriate.

Comment: Read more on [Binomial Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution) versus the [Hypergeometric Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution).  As for "*but I expect an answer of 0.77*", no interpretation of the problem that I can see will give an answer of $0.77$.

Comment: Thank you all! I will think more about this problem!

Comment: @Clone Why you expect $0.77$?

Comment: how about this way.  The first phone you pick, you have 94/100 odds.  Then the 2nd one  there are 99 phones left and 93 ok phones, so next time it is 93/99.  so it is (94/100)(93/99)(92/98)...(80/86) = (94! / 79!) / (100! / 85!) = 0.366891221

Comment: alternatively it's how many ways can you pick 15 from 94 (the number of successful choices you have) divided by how many ways can you pick 15 from 100 = (94! / (15! 79!)) / (100! / (15! 85 !)) =  (94! / (15! 79!))  (15! 85 ! / 100!) = 94! 85! / (79 ! 100!) = 0.366891221 again

Answer (score 1):

Your formula would be appropriate if you actually have 100 phones, 6 of which are faulty, and if you pick 15 phones from those 100 (i.e. select phones without replacement).  However, given that the prompt talks about an 'average' of 6 out of 100 phones being faulty, you really should think about this in terms of probabilities. And note, as such, whether any one phone is faulty is independent of any other phone being faulty, and that is not the case when you pick phones from a group without replacement. So, the two approaches will get different answers.

Comment: I guess in that case, if the 100 phones are selected from the large population at random, then selecting the 6 phones from the 100 is equivalent to selecting any 6 phones from the original large population - thanks for pointing out that subtle point.